Batch error when trying to start a bash shell from a Windows batch file
I had Linux working (many times). Now when I use bash in WSL I get this error:
<3>WSL (329) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:763: 
Failed to translate H:\My Drive\Wayne Bridge\dealer\Dealer-Version-2-\Prod

I have been calling bash from a Windows batch file. The file is simple enough. It has two lines. The first changes the directory and the second calls bash.
I get the same error when I try to do this process manually.

That really isn't a "bash error", it's a Windows error - see for example <3>WSL (358) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:789: Failed to translate Z:/

Thanks but not sure what to do nevertheless. This worked until a week ago.

I am going to make some assumptions here as you have not really supplied much basic data of your rig.
Possibly you are using Windows Subsystem for Linux (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)?
You are most probably using Docker Desktop, Docker Desktop makes it own distro and sets it as default, this is what causes the issue.
wsl --list
wsl --setdefault <DISTRO_NAME>

This may solve your issue.
bash error when trying to start linux (ubantu)
